# Is there a way to make the height of a Drawer's child responsive using Material-UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

*A little bit of context:* I'm using a  temporary drawer from Material-UI with `anchor="right"`. Inside it I have a div as a container of a multi-step form. For the first step of the form the content is smaller than the height of the screen (in this case I want the div to be displayed as 100% of the parent which is the drawer), but for the next 2 steps the content is greater than the height of the screen. In those cases I want to have scrollable content.
*My actual problem:* I figured out how to have either full height of the drawer (for the first step) or scrollable content (for the other 2 steps) but I need to have them all together.  The div containing the form has a different color from the drawer's color (hence why I need those 2 cases working together).
My problem is more related to CSS than Material-UI I suppose.
Here's what I tried so far (using `makeStyles` from Material-UI):

```
//v1
container: {
    height: '100%',
}

//v2
container: {
    minHeight: '100vh',
}

//v3
container: {
    minHeight: '200vh' 
}
```

It appears that using the third variant it works for now but I'm aware that in the future I might have more content that exceeds that value resulting in the same problem.
Material-UI version: `"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3"` (even thought I don't think it's relevant).

Comment: have you tried using flexbox? But first you might want to check if materialUI drawers use it as default.

Comment: @MertYurt Sorry for my late reply. `flex: 1` on container did the job.